# JQGrid .getGridParam getting checked rows as delimited string

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grid, row

Im using

```
var blkstr = jQuery("#toolbar1").getGridParam('selarrrow');
var  roles = $.map(blkstr, function(val,index) {                    
var str = val;
return str;
}).join(",");
alert(roles);
```

The alert is showing exactly like this-  `1,2,3,4`
im trying to POST 'roles' while posting its going something like `2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+1` .
I just need the ids of the row elements checked like `1,2,3,4` to be POSTED to server.

Thanks in advance ,
Abhi

Comment: Where is the code you are using to POST the data? Also, you could try formatting it as JSON or using a different delimiter such as `_`.

Comment: Thanks Justin change of delimeter worked.

Comment: You're welcome! Since this solved your problem I posted it as an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try formatting it as JSON or using a different delimiter such as `_` which will not be escaped in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://192.168.1.2:8080/ConstructionHub/user/createuser?',
        data:{firstName:fname,lastName:lname,uname:uname,password:cpassword,phoneno:phno,address:address,street:street,city:city,state:state,country:country,postbox:postbox,zip:zip,url:url,search:search,weblink:weblink,email:email,roles:roles},
        dataType:'xml',
        contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        crossDomain:true,
        timeout:10000,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            if($(data).find("isException").text() == "false")
            {
                //alert('No Exceptions found');
                if($(data).find("message").text() == "true")
                    onTrue();
                else
                    onFalse();
            }
            else
            {
                alert($(data).find("message").text());
            }
        },

        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  //  alert("Error status :"+textStatus);
                  //  alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);
                    alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                                                           } 
         });
```

Above is the code im using to post.

Answer (score 0):

Which method are you using for post?
Try:
    jQuery.post(url, { roles: roles });

Hope this helps.